# Using Meteor: strange behavior using helper functions in template helpers

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I'm getting some strange behavior using Meteor.

I'm in a template helper defined in client/ . The function "percentCompleted" is a helper function defined in client/lib/helper.js. When I call "percentCompleted" in the return line, percentCompleted completes normally. However, whenever I call percentCompleted outside of the return line, the console logs an error that the function "percentCompleted" is undefined. Why would a helper function be defined or undefined depending on where in the template helper it is called??

This works:

```
Template.chapter.percentComplete = function(){
  if(_.isEmpty(this))
    return "";

  return percentCompleted(this)
}
```

This throws an error with "percentCompleted" undefined.

```
Template.chapter.percentComplete = function(){
  if(_.isEmpty(this))
    return "";

  var percentCompleted = percentCompleted(this)  

  return percentCompleted;
}
```

Comment: Double check the load order.  [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a local variable called `percentCompleted` which shadows the function `percentCompleted`. Rename the variable to something else and it should work.

Note that local variable declarations in Javascript are hoisted to the top of the function, so it behaves as if you wrote:

```js
Template.chapter.percentComplete = function(){
  var percentCompleted;
  if(_.isEmpty(this))
    return "";

  // Here we attempt to call the function in the percentCompleted
  // var, but that is undefined.
  percentCompleted = percentCompleted(this)  

  return percentCompleted;
}
```